# PowerShetll Assembly with same name is already loaded on Az.Storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

Trying to run a powershell script to move a bunch of files on an Azure Storage Account using this command, as described here: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/move-azdatalakegen2item?view=azps-10.0.0)

```
Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $context -Source $blob.Name -Destination $newBlobName
```

However getting the following error:

> Line |
> 28 |          Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $context -Source $blob.Name  …
> | The 'Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item' command was found in the module 'Az.Storage', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error: [Assembly with same name is already loaded] For more information, run
> | 'Import-Module Az.Storage'.

Things I have done

1. Set Execution Policy to Unrestricted
2. Removed old versions of Az and Az.Account:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable Az.Storage
```

> ```
> Directory: C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
> ```
>
> ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
>
> ---
>
> Script     5.7.0                 Az.Storage                          Core,Desk {Get-AzStorageAccount, Get-> AzStorageAccountKey, New-AzStorageAccount, New-AzStorageAccountKey…}

Running this .ps1 script via VSCode. Tried running it with both Windows Powershell or Powershell

**Any ideas/thoughts would be helpful, thank you**

Comment: The error says “For more information, run | 'Import-Module Az.Storage'.” - did you try running ```Import-Module Az.Storage```? What happened?

Comment: Hi, it said Import-Module: Assembly with same name is already loaded

Answer (score 0):

> Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $context -Source $blob.Name … | The 'Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item' command was found in the module 'Az.Storage', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error: [Assembly with the same name is already loaded] For more information, run | 'Import-Module Az.Storage'.

The error message indicates that the **`Az.Storage`** module is already loaded, but it can't be loaded again. This error occurs when you try to load the same module multiple times in the same session.

To resolve the issue, try to remove the module and import once again using the below commands.

```
Remove-module -Name Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.Storage
```

To check the modules are imported you can use the below commands:

```
Get-Module -Name Az.Storage -ListAvailable
```

Also, the issue often occurs because the script can't be performed from the system where it is currently working. you can notice that the option "Run" is disabled in the support tool if you try to build the command using Powershell ISE. This is because the current PowerShell policy has not been initiated by the user, which restricts the number of commands that may be executed.

You can set the execution policy to the current user by following commands.

**Command:**

```
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Once all was done, I tried with one CSV file to move from one filesystem to another filesystem with the below command.

**Command:**

```
Connect-azaccount 

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "venkat098" -UseConnectedAccount

Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item -FileSystem filesystem1 -Path directory1/results.csv  -DestFileSystem filesystem2 -DestPath "test1/sample.csv" -Context $ctx
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Move-AzDataLakeGen2Item (Az.Storage) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/move-azdatalakegen2item?view=azps-10.0.0)

Comment: I managed to get it working today.

I tried a lot but what I ended up doing was going to a greenfield as much as possible... Removing any powershell installs I could find... Removing any modules I could find, in particular removing AzureRM and Azure in any of the modules directories...

Then I reinstalled the Azure module but with the scope AllUsers with elevated rights...

Once I did that, I got through it!